# Java - Space complexity with variable

Tags: java, space-complexity

Is the space complexity here O(n)? Since if k increases by 5, my variable p would also increase by 5.

All this method does right now is get the node at k. For example: 1->5->3, when k = 2, the node is 5.

```
public ListNode reverseKGroup(ListNode head, int k) {
    int p = 1;

    while (p < k) {
        if (head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }
        head = head.next;
        p++;
    }

    return head
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly considering your algorithm, it has a space complexity O(1). Your input is a header of a list and a number `k`, but your algo doesn't consume any space more than just a reference `head` and a number `p`. In my opinion, the existing list doesn't belong to the complexity of your method. However, your time complexity is O(N).

--- answer to Theo's question in the comment:

`p` is a number (in this case of primitive type int, so it takes 4 bytes - constant size). If `p` increases, it doesn't mean, it takes more space, but that a higher number is stored in. E.g. p = 5 means following bytes are set: "0,0,0,5" , for p = 257, bytes are set: "0,0,1,2".
I assume, JVM stores the date in big endian byte order, so the first zero's are representing the bigger bytes. With little endian, the byte order would be reversed.

Of course, you are right, that for very big `N`, the 32 bits long integer is not enought. Therefore, strictly considering this fact, O(log(N)) bits are necessary to store numbers up to `N`.
E.g. a number 2^186 needs 187 bits to be stored (one 1 and 186 zeros).

But in reality, when working with "usual" data, you do not expect such a huge amount. Since only to exceed 32 bit register (one `int` number), you would need to have 2^32 data entries (1 entry = 4 bytes for a next reference, at least 4 bytes for the value `Object` reference, and the object size itself = at least 8 bytes), that is 2^35 bytes = 32 gigabyes. Therefore, when a number is used, it's generally considered to be a constant space complexity. It depends on the task and circumstances.

Comment: I understand the time complexity part. For the space complexity, I know using head doesn't take any space. But can you explain how using number p doesn't take space? Since if I increase k, doesn't p increase by the same amount, and hence my algo takes space for the input k, which is O(n) space complex

Comment: @Theo - my answer is bit longer, see the edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you consider pre-existing structures part of your space complexity, the space complexity is either O(1) or O(N) where N is the length of the list being operated on since you do not add any new nodes and only reference existing nodes.

k only matters for time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The only space this algorithm uses is the space for `int p`, which is constant regardless of input so space complexity is O(1). The time complexity indeed is O(N).